# PHP Routing: How to route www.domain.com/download to a folder that is same level with the domain root folder?

Tags: php, apache, routes, url-routing

I have a site, www.example.com with root folder at C:xampp/htdocs/example.

I want to create a download page for my site, where i want to route it to www.example.com/download.

My colleague kept all the file in C:xampp/htdocs/download.

How can I point www.example.com/download to C:xampp/htdocs/download ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this method, but try inserting something like this in your `.htaccess` file, but first be sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

```
DocumentRoot "xampp/htdocs"
AliasMatch "^/download"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/download"
```

Tell me if it works :)

Comment: If that works, then in apache config may need to give access to download folder. In my case,  I had to add that:  `php_admin_value open_basedir /home/example.com/public_html/:/home/example.com/tmp:/home/example.com/download` (depends what path you have). NOTE: I am using debian box.

Comment: Thank for your fast response man, but I ended up moving the download folder into the root folder, will try on the method you'd suggested later.

Comment: @DamodarBashyal, do you all has experience with having PHP rootfolder with Laravel subfolder?